# window.location.hash at Safari 4.0.4 doesn't increase the history.length

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari

I have a javascript error at the Safari 4.0.4 browser.
I'm using AJAX navigation for the browser, in order to navigate between the result of my AJAX request, but the problem is that sometimes (i couldn't found the exact reasone) the history.lenght stays at the same count, instead of increase its value.

Thanx :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Safari requires some grotesque hacks for this kind of thing. You could either [use a library that has abstracted away all of those hacks](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/history/), or study it to see how they do it.